# Solving for $t$ in $h = 48t + \frac{1}{2}at^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm using an intermediate algebra textbook and it had this problem:

"Solve the formula 
$$h = 48t + \frac{1}{2}a t^2$$ 
for $t$." The answer they displayed was:
$$a = \frac{2h-96t}{t^2}$$

> Can anyone tell me how this answers the question "solve for $t$", and what would be the right way to solve for $t$?

Comment: That is solving for a.

Comment: Maybe they meant solve for a.

Comment: So, what would the answer for solving for t?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to solve for $a$, you want to isolate $a$ to get it by itself.

So first, I'd subtract $48t$ from both sides.

$$h - 48t = \frac{1}{2}at^2$$

Then you can multiply both sides by 2:

$$ 2(h-48t) = at^2$$

and finally dividing both sides by $t^2$

$$a =\frac{2h-96t}{t^2}$$

**Edit:** to solve for $t$, you can use the quadratic formula. For $Ax^2+Bx+C = 0$, we have that

$$x = \frac{-B \pm \sqrt{B^2-4AC}}{2A}$$

So if we have $\frac{1}{2}at^2+48t-h = 0$, we can plug into the equation with $A = \frac{1}{2}a$, $B = 48, C=-h$:

$$t = \frac{-48 \pm \sqrt{48^2 - 4(\frac{1}{2}a)(-h)}}{2(\frac{1}{2}a)}$$

Comment: What would be the answer for solving for t?

Comment: @user65141 see my edit